# FullCalendar -Weekly View

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am working on project and I need to display time on x-axis and customize the events accordingly. 
So how can I display the time on x axis instead of y axis in Full Calendar weekly view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. That view is set the way it is and there's no configuration option to change the display axis. If you want to build your own view that displays it the way you want, you can do that instead and take advantage of the rest of fullCalendar's capabilities at the same time:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-views

You have the option to extend/modify existing views (although the options are relatively limited), or build a new view from scratch. The link above gives detailed examples of both possibilities.

Comment: The Custom_Views link is broken

Comment: @JesonMartajaya fixed, thanks. The fullCalendar site had been updated